# Чем отличаются слова "упасть" и "свалиться"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, общие-вопросы, глаголы, разговорная-речь

Есть ли разница между значениями этих глаголов в простых примерах "упасть с чего-либо" или "свалиться с чего-либо" ? (Например, как будто с дерева, с мотоцикла, с велосипеда, и.т.д...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В ваших примерах - по сути ничем, разве что "свалиться" более разговорный вариант.

Небольшие различия могут проявиться только в отдельных случаях - в особом контексте. 
"Упасть" это совершенный вид к "падать", а сам этот глагол очень многозначный, в некоторых значениях он не является синонимичным "валиться". Например: "жребий пал на NN", тут "свалился"  было бы невозможно.

Однако, если мы ограничиваемся сочетаниями *"упал/свалился с чего/кого"*, то я могу отметить лишь некоторые случаи, близкие к фразеологизмам (упал/свалился с ног, упал/свалился с неба), в которых "свалился" субъективно означает *полностью неконтролируемое падение*, в то время как "упал" - скорее случайное или даже сознательное.

Comment: + 1 Спасибо за уточнения! : )

Comment: Комментарий ко второму абзацу. Если человек просто упал в самом обычном значении этого слова (например, споткнулся или подскользнулся и т.п.), тогда это именно "упал". "Свалился" в подобном значении всегда предполагает падение с чего-то или откуда-то.

Comment: @grizzly - пример для такого толкования можно? У меня во "втором абзаце" речь идет о случаях "упал/свалился с чего/кого". я не представляю, как можно "споткнуться с чего" - если это не о бормотухе сказано.

Comment: У Вас там сказано, что "небольшие различия могут проявляться только в отдельных случаях - в особом контексте". Я добавил, что есть ещё самый обычный и довольно распространённый контекст, в котором проявляется различие. И да, Вы правильно меня поняли — нельзя "споткнуться с чего-то".

Comment: Может, мы по-разному абзацы считаем? Я имел в виду второй из трёх (то есть средний).

Comment: @grizzly Вы первую считаете за абзац? Ну хорошо, а пример будет? Я не чувствую подобной трактовки.  *"Я сильно устал - и, дойдя до кровати, свалился"* - это **откуда**???. .

Comment: Я бы так уже не сказал, но, наверное, за счёт коннотации с устойчивым "свалился от усталости" это ещё будет понято. А если так: "Было скользко — я три раза поскользнулся и один раз даже свалился"? Для меня это звучит уже неграмотным (недопустимым) просторечием.